# Projection on the eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let A be a normal operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ and dim($\mathcal H$) = n . Let $\alpha$ be a eigen value of A and again $E_α$ be the orthonormal projection onto the α-eigenspace . Let {$u_1$ , $u_2$ , ... ,$u_m$ } be an orthonormal basis of the eigen space . Then $E_\alpha$ = $\sum_{i=1}^m u_iu_i^*$ .
I know that $E_\alpha$($\beta$) =  $\sum_{i=1}^m <\beta ,u_i>u_i/||u_i||^2$ . But how can I show this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: complete $\{u_i\}$ to an orthonormal basis, then compute both expressions on a given basis vector. This is a mere formality, though, as it suffices to evaluate in each $u_i$: we already know that $E_\alpha$ and each $u_i^\ast$ are zero in the orthogonal complement of the $\alpha$-eigenspace.

> Indeed, since $u_j$ are in the eigenspace, their are fixed by $E_\alpha$, and the same holds for $\sum_i u_iu_i^\ast(u_j) = \sum_i \delta_{ij}u_i = u_j$.

Comment: Kindly do the formal way to do the math.

Comment: Do you see that $E_\alpha(u_j) = \sum_i u_i u_i^\ast(u_j)$ by the spoiler?

Comment: I know that $\sum_{i=1}^m u_iu_i^*$ is a projection but why this map is same to the definition of the projection map .

Comment: I haven't claimed that yet, I'm asking if you see they coincide at each $u_j$.

Comment: no , why this holds.

Comment: If $v$ is on the $\alpha$-eigenspace, then what is its image $E_\alpha(v)$ under $E_\alpha$?

Comment: $E_\alpha$($\beta$) =  $\sum_{i=1}^m <\beta ,u_i>u_i/||u_i||^2$